# Is there a list of countries that recognize virtual workers who are from the US?

Tags: working-visas

Where can one move abroad while maintaining a "work from home" position with an American organization? What are the unforeseeable consequences of making such a move?

Comment: By definition, we cannot foresee the unforeseeable consequences.

Comment: Unforeseen by me could be foreseen by you!

Comment: Unforseen isn't the same as unforeseeable!

Answer (score 1):

**Working permit**

If you want to be employed in country X, you usually need a working permit in that  country. As a rule, not allowed on tourist visa.

**Legal employment**

You must get employed under the laws of your country of residence. Normally it means that your company from US must open an affiliate, or you open an export company (you export your services).

**Double taxation**

Unless a special agreement between X and US, your income would be taxed both in X and US.

Comment: The US taxes the worldwide income of its citizens and permanent residents in any case, but a non-US citizen not residing in the US would not be subject to US tax for work performed outside the US even if for a US company. US citizens and PRs would need to *file* US tax returns but would likely owe nothing because of the foreign earned income exclusion.

Comment: Unless they earn more than around $100K in the tax year. But US citizens who earn anything at all must always file a tax return even when abroad (and sometimes when they don't earn anything - if only just to make that point)

Answer (score 0):

For this Cambodia is the easy Country to do it in. You can get the work visa at the airport on arival there. Only 2 cities with the internet speed you would need. Very cheap to live there. A good number of expats there who do this.  Philippines is a good Country to do this on a long term visa. Renew every 6 months. You can work internet there as long as none is done inside the Philippines.  All contacts would need be outside of the Philippines You would need a major city for good internet. Not like were I am with only slow WiFi. Some seem to like Daveo for this work. As long as it is all online work. Check them both out. Philippines has the advantage of most speak English. Keep your pay in a U.S. account. Use your debit card for cash. No tax on money from overseas. You still need to pay U.S. tax on income. Maylasia you need hire 1 helper there.

Comment: For Cambodia, it might be best to check out the recent rules: https://www.cambodiadaily.com/archives/work-permits-now-required-for-foreigners-67224/. For the Phillipines, maybe start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Philippines. I reccommend you update this post with more detailed information.